# Tkinter Scrollbar - Problem allways maximized

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have a problem that I could not solve, thanks to many of you I was able to order the tree with the scrollbar, the problem now is that the scrollbar is always maximized, it does not calculate the amount of data that is inside.

```
        frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.wind, corner_radius=5)
        frame.pack(expand="true")
        

        button_llegue = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, corner_radius=8,fg_color="IndianRed3",hover_color="IndianRed4", text='Llegue',command=self.add_fecha)
        button_llegue.grid(row = 0, column = 0,pady=(20,10),padx=(15,15))

        button_sali = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, corner_radius=8,fg_color="PaleGreen3",hover_color="PaleGreen4", text='Me Voy',command=self.add_fecha)
        button_sali.grid(row = 0, column = 1,pady=(20,10),padx=(15,15))


        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(master=frame,height = 10, selectmode="browse")
        self.tree.grid(row = 1,column=0,pady=(10,20),columnspan=2,sticky="NWSE",padx=(15,15))
        self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Ultimos registros', anchor = CENTER)
     
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame,orient='vertical',command=self.tree.yview)
        scrollbar.grid(row = 1, column=0, sticky="NSE",pady=(10,20),columnspan=2,padx=(0,15))
        
 
        self.get_fechas()
```

[image]

Comment: Remove E. Should be scrollbar.grid(row = 1, column=0, sticky="NS",

Comment: you use `command=self.tree.yview` to connect `scrollbar` to `treeview` (so scrollbar can send information to treeview when you scroll it) but it may need also other function to connect `treeview` to `scrollbar` to send information from `treeview` to `scrollbar` that it has to change size when you add items to `treeview`.

Comment: Toyota i try remover they E but its nots they problem, furas what function is that???. Than youu

Comment: I have only [example for listbox](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/listbox/listbox-scrollbar/main.py) - `listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)` - but in `treeview` it may need the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using `command=self.tree.yview` you send information from `scrollbar` to `treeview` - and it will scroll `treeview` when you will move `scrollbar`.

But you need also

```
self.tree.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

to send information from `treeview` to `scrollbar` - and it will change size and position of `scrollbar` when you will add elements to `treeview` or when you will scroll `treeview` directly (using mouse wheel).

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode="browse")
tree.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=tree.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

tree.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

for x in range(1, 21):
    print(tree.insert('', 'end', text=str(x)))

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: it worked perfect!!! thank you very much, just add that line